# Kafka Streams Join after aggregation not working with multiple partition

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Problem Statment:

Topic 1: "key = empId, value = empname, **deptName**, ..."

Topic 2: "key = **deptName**, value = deptName"

I need the data from Topic 1 where the deptName(value attribute in topic 1) is equal to key of Topic 2.

Steps:

1. Create a stream from Topic 1, group it by deptName, and do aggregatation.
   It will return Ktable `(key =deptName, value = "empId1,empId2,empId3 ..")`
2. Create a stream from Topic 2 `(key ="deptName" value = "deptName")`
3. Perform a left join operation on Ktable (Step 1) and KSteam (Step2). `(KStream-Ktable)`
4. And join returns desired result.

**Everything works as expected in single partition, however, after switching to multiple partitions, join doesn't return any data.**

Step 1:

```
KGroupedStream<String, Object> groupedStream = adStream.groupBy((key, value) -> value.getOrganizationId().toString());
        groupedStream
                .aggregate(() -> (new String()),
                        (aggKey, newValue, aggValue) -> addCurrentValue(aggValue,
                                String.valueOf(newValue.getOriginId())),
                        Materialized.as("aggregated-stream-store").with(strSerde, strSerde))
                .toStream().to(Constant.AD_AGGREGATED_DATA, Produced.with(strSerde, strSerde));
```

Step 2:

```
KStream<String, String> swgOrgStream = builder.stream(Constant.SWG_ORG_TOPIC,Consumed.with(strSerde, strSerde));
```

Step 3:

```
 KStream<String, String> filteredOrgStream = swgOrgStream.leftJoin(aggregatedTable,
                (leftValue, rightValue) -> rightValue);
```

Comment: I see that in step 1 you are grouping using ` value.getOrganizationId().` is that correct?

Comment: Why are you reading the second topics as `KStream`? Seems it would be better to read it as a `KTable` and do table-table join instead? -- In fact, you would even read the first topic as a `KTable`, too (instead of a stream and an aggregation) and do FK-table-table join?

Comment: I tried FK table join , but the approach didn't give the expected result.

Comment: @TuyenLuong, yes thats correct.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, Thanks for your opinion. I can try that out. However, do you see any issue in implemetation?